# Country and City dropdown for django model

Tags: django-models

I am trying to make a django model to get user address including country and city.Please give a guidance to have a drop down list of countries and cities.

Answer (score 1):

You can use django-cities-light (https://github.com/yourlabs/django-cities-light). It has a pre-populated database. But if you want to use your own database create a model of city and a model of country with city as foreign key. Then add city field as a foreign key in your address model.

```
class Address(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey('City')

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country')
```

Comment: thank you for reply, after installing django-cities-light what command I use to import the field to model?

Comment: Use foreign keys like this:

For city field:   city = models.ForeignKey('cities_light.City', verbose_name='city')

and for country field:   country = models.ForeignKey('cities_light.Country', verbose_name='country')

Comment: as per the instructions on github, I have installed app, added to installed apps migrated and finally updated data. When I use as you mentioned above I am getting error 'ValueError: Related model u'cities_light.City' cannot be resolved'